# Unity3D, Parse.com not sending push notifications to Android Devices

Tags: android, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I am using the parse.com to save an installation (on Android devices) of my Unity3D Games. I want to use **parse.com push service** to manage push notifications. I am able to save all  installations on parse Database in **parse core**.

When I try to send push notifications to my Android devices, it shows the result 0 pushes sent.

**Does anybody know what might be causing this?**

My Manifest is settled according to guide provided in the documentation.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="18" android:versionName="1.1.7" package="com.imptrax.sniperoverkill3dassassinshooting" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <permission android:name="com.imptrax.sniperoverkill3dassassinshooting.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.imptrax.sniperoverkill3dassassinshooting.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity">
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\ 1550186055254706" />
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" />
    <!-- Required by Chartboost -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBDialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|layoutDirection|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|layoutDirection|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize" android:name="com.prime31.GoogleIABProxyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <service android:name="com.parse.ParsePushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
    -->
        <category android:name="com.imptrax.sniperoverkill3dassassinshooting" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Its my piece of code to register for push notifications written in C# for Unity

```
void Start() {
    var installation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;
    installation.SaveAsync();
    ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += (sender, args) =>
    {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        AndroidJavaClass parseUnityHelper = new AndroidJavaClass("com.parse.ParseUnityHelper");
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        // Call default behavior.
        parseUnityHelper.CallStatic("handleParsePushNotificationReceived", currentActivity, args.StringPayload);
    #endif
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your package in **permissions** and in your **uses-permission** tag

As you have specified a pakage name in your **manifest** tag copy that and place it like this

```
com.unity3d.player.permission......
```

both in **permission** and **uses-permission**

check if that helps